# Drawing contour in gnuplot like this attached image

Tags: csv, ubuntu, gnuplot

How can I draw this contour in gnuplot? I have data in csv format.

[image: Example plot]

My data:

```
lat     long      height 
26.615  29.889  15.80815
21.342  30.151  17.05494
29.784  27.87   10.09826
30.651  31.184  9.72935
26.257  29.084  16.9081
22.37   30.608  17.82171
30.413  27.221  11.43493
23.225  30.526  17.38659
25.457  31.954  17.1296
31.057  29.882  12.00676
27.17   31.226  17.18103
22.866  32.532  17.97127
31.297  29.282  13.30918
25.901  33.762  13.27969
29.575  34.879  11.66679
22.579  25.899  17.11153
```

Comment: Neither your data nor an example graph is attached to the question. Perhaps you can try again to attach them so that other people understand what you have tried and what you are trying to produce.

Comment: click on the link above

Comment: You seem to have three links to the same image and have not included any data to plot nor an image to plot them on... it's rather hard to help you at the moment.

Comment: Please click `edit` under your question and paste your data there. Then select it with the mouse and click `{}` near `Bold` and `Italics` in the editing menu.

Comment: Thanks , I edited it